# php save a file as bin will write to many 0000

Tags: php, binary, hex, fwrite, pack

I came up with a php script that will save the info into a bin file but the problem is will add to many 0000

script:

```
<?php
$name = 'username';
$pass = '   password';
$pass .= pack('i', dechex($pass));
$fp = fopen($name.'.usr','w+');
fwrite($fp,$pass);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

this will save a file username.usr and inside it save

```
0970 6173 7377 6f72 6400 0000 00
```

equivalent of

```
TABpassword
```

Well I want to save only the first 2 00 after "password"and nothing after.
Should be 0970 6173 7377 6f72 6400
And if it was

```
$pass = '  passwords';
```

should be

```
0970 6173 7377 6f72 6473 00
```

Any help in this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

changed pack "i" to "C" and did the job